# Draw on canvas on different screen resolutions and densities

Tags: android, draw, android-canvas, screens

I have the following situation:
I want to draw an rectangle on a canvas and inside the rectangle a text of a certain size.
How can I make the rectangle have 1/4 width of the screen on all screen sizes, and how can I know what setTextSize to give to the inside text in order to not exceed the rectangle boundaries ?
I have read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but I'm not fully clear with the concepts.

Comment: funny... :) Actually (if you can believe it) no, I just want to know from someone that has some experience what are the general guidelines when working with canvas in order to achieve the same results on all display types.

Comment: Can you please update us if you have found a way ?

Comment: Read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625208/working-with-canvas-in-different-screen-sizes/8626456#8626456 It's actually about HTML5 Canvas and not the android canvas but the same idea should apply.