# What is the best way to scale contents of a realtime whiteboard

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a whiteboard with angularjs, socketio an node.js.

As long as I use a fixed width/height for the canvas everywhere I can just broadcast the coordinates of the mouse/touch event and recreate the graphic in realtime. However, the problem I am facing is when trying to make the canvas have different sizes across different platforms (think desktop and a smartphone), the canvas has to be scaled and so does the graphic, but this makes things pretty slow.

The approach I am currently taking is to draw the graphic in a temporary hidden canvas of original size, then when there is a pause in the drawing stream (in other words the user has stopped doodling), I scale and copy it to the main canvas. The problem with this is, it doesn't feel very realtime at all, especially when a user keeps doodling without a pause for a while. Another approach I could try is to push all the coordinates in an array, apply 2d affine transformation on it, then redraw the entire thing. Though this too doesn't seem like a good solution for when the array size increases, repeatedly trying to apply transformations in realtime can easily eat up a lot of resources.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Draw a line between the most recent mouse/touch event and the previous one. Broadcast it along with some kind of reference width or height figure to base your calculation off of. On your other client, divide the given width or height with the local width/height, then multiply that number by the X and Y coordinates of the given line data. Draw it and forget it. You now have a line drawn to scale and it cost you a couple nano seconds to calculate with basically zero memory overhead.

Comment: @nick, That's a good idea and that is why I was looking at the 2d affine transformations thing mainly, but the problem is would just scaling individual lines accurately reflect curves and angle scaling of a completed shape?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response- let me write up a full answer

Answer (score 0):

do it with css scale transform. Scale the canvas to fit the size of the device be it a mobile, desktop, or tablet, or whatever.

Have your canvas be fixed width across all devices. Say it's 640px by 480px. Now we'll resize it to fit whatever window.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  var w = 640; // $('#mycanvas').width();
  var h = 480; // $('#mycanvas').height();

  var newWidth = $(window).width(); // this could be either smaller or bigger than the canvas
  var newHeight = $(window).height(); // same here

  var scaleX = newWidth / w;
  var scaleY =  newHeight / h;

  $('#mycanvas').css('transform','scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY +')');
    $('#mycanvas').css('-webkit-transform','scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY +')');
});
```

note: mycanvas could also be a container if any kind that holds the canvas and other divs or whatever. just make sure that w is the width of that container, etc.

note: if someone uses their fingers to draw across the screen, you may need to convert it from scaled coordinates to fixed width (640x480) coordinates.

---

Btw, I found a different way to do this that might be better. not sure:

[Scaling canvas element with static resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742131/scaling-canvas-element-with-static-resolution)

Comment: This is not a good solution because allowing the canvas to scale disproportionally will also allow the its content to deform (squish/stretch). Instead calculate a single scaling factor that maintains the original aspect ratio and apply that single scaling factor to both the height and width.

Comment: yeah that's true, I just wanted to give the basic css scale example.