# Display canvas in smaller size while maintaining resolution

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to create an online tool using html/javascript where users can upload their pictures that are imported into a canvas and then they can overlay other pictures on top of them, resize and move them around. To add this, I'm using fabric.js.

I do want to maintain the Image resolutions while I do this, so I have to resize the canvas according to the size of the base image which can get out of hand if the image is 4000px wide. What I'd like to do is display the images in a limited area such as 1000x1000 while maintaining the original size to provide the users with the original resolution when they are done. I tried messing around with CSS to limit the canvas display size but unlike img, canvas seems to override the limits I specify. I'm also using github pages to host this.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: heres a good answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742200/2336212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd keep track of my images separately from my rendering layer. So, I'd either keep them in a hash or array in memory or, if that's too expensive, I'd persist them to storage (server side or in S3 or whatever).

Then, you just render low(er)-fidelity images to your canvas.

Comment: so keep track of the performed operations on the low-fidelity canvas and mirror them to the high quality images when the user exports the final result?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I'd do. Basically, you have 2 versions of each pic (high-fi and low-fi). While the user is editing, you're using low-fi so the edits are quick. When they want to export or whatever, you show a processing indicator, change the sources to be the high-fi versions, and do the export.